# Saint-like template/prestige class for villains

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, prestige-class

The *Book of Exalted Deeds* offers the Saint template for good-aligned characters. This template is quite powerful, but has strict prerequisites (as described in Sainthood section).

Is there any equivalent template/prestige class designed for evil heroes and villains? I am looking for something official that can stand against a Saint character. Beyond powerful mechanics, I am looking for something like a good background/prerequisite/sacrifice (similar to the Sainthood section of the Saint template) and suitable powers for the chosen of a god.

I am looking for something more the evil version of the Saint. My gaming group has a Saint character and I am looking for something that would represent the evil god they are fighting. They are fighting the god's minions (god of undead) and I am in search for a NPC suitable to be the leader of the minions. Also, the group must realize that the NPC is something like the Saint in their group: the chosen champion of the evil god.

Comment: Ghost. Evil ghost whose unfinished business is that he never finished his last great act of villainy. Abilities aren't exactly a match, but the fluff is a pretty close mirror-image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**That I am aware of, there is no official template**

If there was, it'd be in *The Book of Vile Darkness*, or else one of the *Fiend Folios*. I'm sad to say that I don't believe there's a template that mirrors Saint in terms of flavor or mechanics.

**But...**

I can propose some adjustments for you. Try doing this to the Saint template:

**Requirements:** Swap the requirement for a Good alignment with a requirement for an Evil one. Swap the prerequisite Exalted feats for Vile feats, and require a great act of evil in the name of a dark god (personal suggestion: a sacrifice of good-aligned sapient beings equal to double the character's hit dice).

**Numerical Bonuses:** Swap all instances of "perfection" bonuses with "profane" bonuses in the same areas. You can probably leave the energy resistance alone.

**Spell-Like Abilities:** Check and see which of the SLAs are distinctly "good" and replace them with evil ones. Some of them can probably stay, however, so don't go too crazy here.

Everything else, if I remember correctly, can remain the same.

**Prestige Classes**

There's a couple of prestige classes that might be useful to you if the villain in question is a fiend (an evil-aligned outsider) - namely, Fiend of Blasphemy and Fiend of Corruption, both of which can be found in the various *Fiend Folios*. These prestige classes give powers that help the fiend to corrupt, debase, and destroy souls in the names of greater patrons (or just Evil Itsownself) and could be very useful in your endeavor.

Answer (score 4):

**Corrupted**

BoVD has the Corrupted template that, as far as I can tell, is supposed to be the evil compliment to saint. As templates go, it's not too bad, providing some nice "I'm so evil" perks to cement the villain in the party's minds.

Answer (score 1):

As DM rename it and any abilities that would sound funny on a bad guy, and use it in spite of its "restrictions".

Comment: I'm... not sure what you're referring to by "it," nor how this is answering the question: is "it" suitable for leading minions, representing the chosen champion of a god of undeath, or any of the other points? Please edit your answer so we can tell!

Comment: In this case "it" is the Saint template that the question is about.